# Free installer make it easy to install application as Windows services?

Tags: c#, java, .net, c++, windows

Is there any free installer allow user to seamlessly install a software that could also install Windows service?

There are a few ways like sc.exe but in Windows Vista and 7, they are denied by default unless they user grant themselves as administrator.

Hope there a software make life easy for developers.

I did tried a comprenehsive tutorial but end up getting an error on W7 64bit. Not sure for others platform:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-a-simple-windows-service-in-csharp

Tried all the available .Net installutil from 2.0 32/64bits to 4.0, non-worked. I would appreciate to have a solution soon for major project!

```
D:\install>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe setup
.exe
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Installation utility Version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\inst
all\setup.exe' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an
 assembly manifest..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/) with the [NSIS UAC plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/UAC_plug-in), then use [NsSCM](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsSCM_plug-in) or similar.

Comment: Great suggestion! I knew Winamp since they were first release, I never knew the installer became matured today like a jQuery.